# which the easiest way to donwload an image from sql and import to imageView?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, image

as mentioned in the title, which is the easiest way to retrieve an image from sql and show it on image view?
I'm really new into Android world and I would like to achieve something without copy and paste other's code.

the images are stored in the sql as url in the webserver and not ad blob file.

What do you think about it?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You should use Glide. 
There are plenty of alternatives- https://medium.com/mindorks/android-top-image-loading-libraries-95c9813b506

Answer (score 0):

[Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/) is a great and simple library that can help you download/cache and manipulate images on android